# Is there such a thing as a digital millivolt thermostat that needs no batteries?

Tags: hvac

I only just discovered that there is such a thing as a [millivolt thermostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermostat#Millivolt_thermostats) in the first place (after unwittingly using one for the past 19 years  `:I`  ), so do go easy on me.

It seems like it might be possible to make such electronics (temperature sensor, low-end microcontroller, LCD — doesn't have to be programmable or anything, nuthin' fancy) operate on very small amounts of power, even as small as that supplied by a wall-mounted gas furnace's pilot-light thermopile, if trying hard enough.  I'm imagining some kind of "[joule thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief)" type circuitry that feeds a capacitor and has voltage regulation and whatnot, so the rest of it can pretend it's working on an ordinary 5V/3.3V/whatever-even-lower-voltage power supply.  Which seems like it should conceivably work so long as it doesn't need much actual (milli)wattage.

Has anyone done this, so I don't have to care about batteries in yet another device?

I tried searching around on the web quite a bit for such a thing, but no one makes it easy to get this specific, and a lot of what you do find turns out to be simply wrong when you go to verify it with the manufacturer…

(Before someone inevitably asks why I want such a thing, it's mainly about the wide temperature swings I'm getting with the new electromechanical/bimetal/etc. one I have now.)

---

Additional information:

- I rent, so I'm not at liberty to do unlimited mods to the place
- Pipes don't freeze here, so that is not a design goal
- The point of this is to have a tighter temperature range (for my comfort) *and* not to have to mess with batteries, ever (for my laziness)

Comment: Why would the power source cause large temperature swings?

Comment: Not the power source, but the regulation technology.  I asked because there are digital ones that work on batteries, and electromechanical ones that work with no batteries.  I'm looking for the best of both worlds here.

Comment: Although it's almost certainly possible, I'd expect the ROI on such a device to be non-existent. The cost on replacement batteries over the lifetime of battery-powered ones would be so small that a manufacturer would never be able to sell them for enough to cover their R&D efforts.

Comment: There is the Honeywell Q313 Thermopile Generator which contains multiple thermocouples connected in series to increase the millivoltage output. The power generated is sufficient to operate an automatic millivolt gas control system, independent of any outside power source.

Comment: @brhans It's not the cost I care about, it's the having to replace batteries

Comment: @SteveWellens This is just a regular thermopile.  It's what I'm seeking to power a digital thermostat by

Comment: I left a comment about the original digital that required 17-24v that did not have batteries they did not last because a power loss over an hour and they lost there memory, decided to replace with:  you could use a small power supply at the correct voltage and a large capacitor to do what you want or purchase a thermostat electric cell that is at the correct voltage and capacity for the temperature range although the thermo electric cells will cost 1000 x the cost of batteries over a lifetime

Comment: I have read all the comments and your query and have no idea as to what you are trying to accomplish. A better explanation of your needs is necessary for me to provide any input.

Comment: It's not your ROI I'm thinking of, it's the ROI of the company which would develop & sell the device - I doubt they'd be able to sell enough of them at enough of a profit to make the effort worthwhile.

Comment: @d.george It's very simple:  the electromechanical one I have now gives me wide temperature swings during normal operation, which digital ones don't.  So I want a digital one.  But I don't want to have to mess with batteries, ever.  There's the rub.

Comment: @brhans But you based your assessment on consumers' only concern being the monetary cost of batteries.  Additionally, the R&D would be pretty minimal; these are not new concepts I'm bringing up

Comment: Yeah... our rules don't really permit radical changes in the nature of a question.   [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) isn't the half of what's happening here.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have not changed anything about the nature of the question, much less radically…

Comment: That sort-of proves my point though - powering the thermostat from the thermocouple is not a radical idea. So as an electronics engineer myself  I'm sure one of the engineers in the R&D departments of a manufacturer like Honeywell would have already made the proposal - if there's no product already on the market then it's likely that the bean-counters shot the idea down.

Answer (score 2):

### Thermocouples are cheap

Forget poaching. The current is sourced from a **thermocouple** which is sitting in the flame of the pilot light.  All of its current is needed to energize the gas flow valve.  It doesn't have spare current to also charge a smart 'stat.

Why not just stick a second thermocouple in the fire, and use that *exclusively* to run a boost module (Joule Thief) to power the 'stat?

### What you *really* want is a Nest, though.  So do it.

Or other "better" 24-volt-based thermostat.

Millivolt systems absolutely can have multiple thermostats in parallel.  So you retain your original, "dumb" millivolt thermostat and set it to 50F so it effectively does not operate. (we'll come back to why to keep it).  **Then, you add a second thermostat *of your choice* to operate the furnace most of the time**.

There are 2 hitches with the Nest (or other 24V 'stats): First, it needs 24VAC from somewhere, but I'll leave that to you.  Second, it needs to throw high DC current at very low voltage, which it's not designed to do.  The solution to this problem is a 24V-coil relay with hefty contacts - e.g. an air conditioning contactor, or a 30A automotive relay. (they make those with 24V coils).

At this point the Nest calls for heat by operating the relay. This connects the thermocouple to the gas valve.

When power fails, the Nest stops working.  It is designed for furnaces *which require AC power to function*, so the Nest simply goes inoperative without 24VAC.  Temperature will slowly fall to 50F, at which point *the old* thermostat will kick on!  That will protect from pipe freeze.  If occupants are present, they can set it to 70F if they prefer.

Comment: Why I don't add a second thermopile is because now we're talking about modifying the heater and running wires through walls and I'm only a renter.  The parallel-thermostat scenario would be useful for preventing pipe-freeze, but that doesn't happen here anyway — what I'm after is to prevent wide temperature swings during normal operation, while not having to mess with batteries, ever.  At this point, it's looking like my only option is to get one that takes external power, then drape an ugly cord over to some outlet.  Guh.

Comment: @Atario If "how do I keep millivolt thermostats from having poor temperature control" was your question, I probably would have written a very different answer.  But you asked what you asked, and in hindsight it sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which are bad for a variety of reasons.  Anyway the weak foundational point in this house of cards is your assumption (all millivolt thermostats vary temp wildly).  No.

Comment: Well, no, my *observation* (not assumption) is that *electromechanical* (not millivolt) thermostats have way more hysteresis than digital ones (which generally operate on an explicit single-degree-Fahrenheit-resolution basis).  If you have some other way, I'm all ears…

Comment: @Atario alright.  But then I come back to my 24V advice. I see no reason my whole shebang - relay, Nest and all - couldn't be put in a project box and mounted at the site of the original thermostat.  Use a commodity 24VAC wall-wart. Done and dusted.  *lol now I want to do that here*...

Comment: I don't know if this applied when the original answer was posted but it appears Nest thermostats available today can run off 5 volts to a micro-USB port on the back, and has a built in rechargeable battery to keep it operating for short periods where power from 24VAC or 5VDC is lost.  Maybe put solar panels on the wall around the thermostat to avoid a need for running a cord or changing out batteries.  It's quite likely nonsense to do this but perhaps some of what I added gives someone a better idea.

Comment: @MacGuffin yeah they had the battery all along, that's how the ones that don't need a C wire are able to survive when they short R and W together to call for heat.